# how to hide or show fields when someone click radio button

Tags: javascript, forms

I want to hide/show couple of input fields when someone clicks yes or no radio button. but not able to do it.

here is the form fields. I want when someone click on yes div should show and when clicks on no it should be hidden also by default it should be hidden.

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[name='prev_occ']").click(function() {
    if ($("#chkYes").is(":checked")) {
      $("#dvmilitry").show();
    } else {
      $("#dvmilitry").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="prev_occ" type="radio" id="chkYes">
<input name="prev_occ" type="radio" id="chkNo">
<div id="dvmilitry" style="display: none">
  <input name="prev_org" type="text" class="textBoxDashed" id="prev_org" value="" size="43" maxlength="50">
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ctyh1s1z/. What errors are you getting? Did you include jQuery?

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: this is what i have included.

Comment: OK, so have you checked the console for errors? As you can see by the fiddle I posted, what you have in your question works.

Comment: i checked but there is no errors there. but i am getting lightbox function error in jquery.

Comment: Welp, I also put your code in a snippet in your question and it works there.

Comment: did you tried clearing cache in your browser or try different browser ?

Comment: @ravi - yes i tried

Comment: .I would note that `.on('change', function(){` may be a better event here

Comment: `$("#dvmilitry").toggle($("#chkYes").is(":checked"));` same effect as all the conditional logic.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss - i dont know why its not working in my page. its working fine here in jsfiddle. i have included jquery library

Answer (score -2):

**Add jQuery Library on script tag and it will work fine**

```js
    $(function () {
        $("input[name='prev_occ']").click(function () {
            if ($("#chkYes").is(":checked")) {
                $("#dvmilitry").show();
            } else {
                $("#dvmilitry").hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="prev_occ" type="radio" id="chkYes">
<input name="prev_occ" type="radio" id="chkNo" >

<div id="dvmilitry" style="display: none">
<input name="prev_org" type="text" class="textBoxDashed" id="prev_org" value="" size="43" maxlength="50">                                
</div>
```

Comment: Other than an older version of jQuery, your code is the same as what the OP posted

Comment: In the above code, there is no error, but the jQuery file is missing

Comment: as u can see i hv added latest version of jquery. but its not working on mypage.

Comment: add the oldest version of jquery file, and it works fine

Comment: @VinaysinghKhetwal - i did this, but still not working there.

Comment: @GauravSingh you copied my jQuery script file as it is?

Comment: @VinaysinghKhetwal - i dont know why its not working in my page. its working fine here in jsfiddle. i have included jquery library also ( old and new both version checked) . but its not working.